# Modifying a basic auth authorization flow with spring security?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, basic-authentication

Right now, I'm using the grails spring security plugin with the following configuration:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.basic.realmName = "MyApp"
```

This works great for basic auth, but I also need to allow and manage authentication through a separate service that relies on cookies. How can I hook into the spring security plugin to also allow for custom service endpoint authentication *or* basic authentication?

Comment: I don't do grails but this [tutorial](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) might help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grails Spring Security Core documentation gives an example of doing exactly what you want: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/9%20Authentication.html#9.1%20Basic%20and%20Digest%20Authentication

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

This essentially leaves the basic auth in place on an API endpoint, while keeping the traditional auth in place for everything else.